# Autoit 3 Generic Keypress

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, listener, autoit

It seems like there should be a generic keypress listener, something like this:

```
hotkeysset("listener")

func listener(key)
    msgbox(0, "Key", "You pressed " & key)
endfunc

while true
    sleep(100)
wend
```

But short of writing a script that generates the appropriate hotkeyset calls for each key on my keyboard, I can't figure out how to do that.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Check out this UDF (User-Defined Function), [IsPressed_UDF](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/86296-ispressed-udf-v22-get-it-now/).