# Replicate text from AutoIt form to Notepad

Tags: windows, autoit, notepad

I am using this AutoIt code to send text to Notepad on the press of a button:

```
#include <ButtonConstants.au3>
#include <EditConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
$Form = GUICreate("Replicate text to notepad", 615, 50, 190, 122)
$Input = GUICtrlCreateInput("Placeholder text", 0, 0, 609, 21)
$Button = GUICtrlCreateButton("Send to notepad", 0, 24, 609, 25)
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)

While 1
    $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $nMsg
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            Exit
        Case $Button
            Example(GUICtrlRead($Input))

    EndSwitch
WEnd

Func Example($text)

    Run("notepad.exe")

    Local $hWnd = WinWait("[CLASS:Notepad]", "", 10)

    ControlSend($hWnd, "", "Edit1", $text)

EndFunc
```

It is working great. But now I want to send keystrokes as soon as I press them. Is there something like OnKeyDown in AutoIt? So I don't have to press the send button to send it to Notepad every time I type a character.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642324/autoit-3-generic-keypress

Comment: No duplicate because he asks for any kind of possible solution.
IsPressed is not a good solution for this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it.
Work pretty neat!

```
#include <ButtonConstants.au3>
#include <EditConstants.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>


Run("notepad.exe")
Global $hWnd = WinWait("[CLASS:Notepad]", "", 10)

$Form = GUICreate("Replicate text to notepad", 615, 50, 190, 122)
$Input = GUICtrlCreateInput("Placeholder text", 0, 0, 609, 21)
$Button = GUICtrlCreateButton("Send to notepad", 0, 24, 609, 25)
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)

$OldText = ""

While 1
    $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()

    $NewText = GUICtrlRead($Input)
    If $OldText <> $NewText Then
        $OldText = $NewText
        Example($NewText)
    EndIf

    Switch $nMsg
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
            Exit
        Case $Button
            Example(GUICtrlRead($Input))

    EndSwitch
WEnd

Func Example($text)
    ControlSetText($hWnd, "", "Edit1", $text)
EndFunc
```